# ASP.NET: How to validate a number input and format it with thousand separator on fly?

Tags: asp.net, validation

On ASP.Net form, I have a couple input fields which only integer allowed and maximum is 8 digital. right after entering value to the textbox field, it will check the validation. after passing the validation, it will format it with thousand separator. all these happen on fly.
I use Regular Express to do the validation. for example: Regex="^-?\d+{0,8}$".
My question is: I can use this regex to check the input and format it with thousand separator, but when hit save button, it fails on validation(Page.IsValid) because the textbox value will show number with commas(,).
For example: since the field only takes integer,when user enter 20000, it pass regex check at first, but after it format with 20,000 it fails the validation.
So how can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom validator
[How to: Validate with a Custom Function for ASP.NET Server Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sree. But I want this happen on fly. My understand is it has to be on client side and done by javascript.